# Instagram API media/comments not showing recent comments

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

While the Instagram API documentation at https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/ suggests that the most recent comments for the media would be returned, the API seems to be returning the first 30 comments on the media.

Is it possible to get all the comments for a media or to get the comments in descending order of created_time?

Comment: Side note: IG is deprecating the old API this year. This is the new one: https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/

Comment: Yes we intend to move to those APIs soon. However we are facing issues with the current Instagram APIs. On more investigation, it looks to me that missing comments are not due to sort order. Most of the missing comments seems to be from Private Account. But there are few comments missing from Public Accounts as well.